# Using local path with WebView (Webkit)

Tags: gtk, webkit

I'm trying to use Gtk port of Webkit. All works fine. But when I'm using local path in src attribute to load image from my HDD (src="file://...") I'm getting the next warning in console:

> not allowed to load local resource
>   file://...

And image doesn't loading. Any suggestions?

**P.S**. I'm using load_string method with fake base url (fake://url).

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: This is Vala code:

webview.load_string("<img src='file:///home/tmpuser/proj/test.png' />", "text/html", "utf8", "fake://url");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `"file://"` as the base URL, then it should work. It's unclear to me whether this is a bug and whether it should also work if the base URL is `NULL` (it doesn't), but see the discussion starting [here on the webkit-dev mailing list](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2009-May/007658.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
WebKitWebSettings *s = webkit_web_settings_new();
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(s),"enable-file-access-from-file-uris", TRUE, NULL);
webkit_web_view_set_settings(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit),s);
```