# How to serve static files using a webkit view in a python gtk application?

Tags: python, webkit, static-files

I am building a gtk desktop application. The main part of my views are HTML. So I make use of the Python implementation of Webkit. The problem is, that I cant include images, as Webkit does not allow to load images from local file system:

```
<img src="file://{{media_url}}_theme/media/img/eft.png"/>
```

=> This will cause a "Not allowed to load local resource".

Is there a way to load static files like images or css-files locally?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834122/using-local-path-with-webview-webkit

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 to encode your images as texts that can be included in your html pages.

Answer (score 0):

@Skami 18's answer seems like a good direction. Maybe then use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to actually set the `src` attribute?