# WebKitGtk doesn't load local files

Tags: c++, c, webkit, webkitgtk

I've tried loading a local html file using `webkit_web_view_load_uri()` with a `file://` URL. However, the webview would display a blank page. To circumvent this, I tried using `webkit_web_view_load_html()` and it worked correctly.

Now that I'm trying to load some images in the html using the `<img>` tag, the images aren't loaded (It displays a blank page).

I'm puzzled because I tried before (~ 2 months ago) a similar method and it worked.

Note: I copied the contents of the generated HTML into a file and loaded it with Firefox and it worked as it should (The images are visible), but with another WebKitGtk application I had lying around the images didn't load.

Note: I'm using C++ as the main programming language (I'd prefer having C++ types in the solutions only if possible)

Note: I have set `webkit_settings_set_allow_file_access_from_file_urls()` and `webkit_settings_set_allow_universal_access_from_file_urls()` to `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve this. The solution had NOTHING to do with webkitgtk, which is strange. It seems that the application was trying to download the page instead of loading it. This traces to a faulty MIME type database.

**Tl;Dr:**

Execute this:

```
rm ~/.local/share/mime/packages/user-extension-html.xml
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

and use `webkit_web_view_load_uri()` instead of `webkit_web_view_load_html()` with a `file://` URI

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have affected many people recently on Arch. Ulauncher got many bug reports out of the blue for our Preferences view (built with WebkitGTK). We changed the implementation to registering a custom scheme with `register_uri_scheme` and then serving the files with the correct mimetypes (ignoring the local mimetypes) from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in C. You have to explicitly set `file://` as base_uri when you call `webkit_web_view_load_html()`.

See also [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834122/using-local-path-with-webview-webkit)